# Tally all values from multiple fields

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a table with several 'values'  and corresponding 'quantities', i.e. Value1 =56   value1qty=7, value2=15   value2qty=563. Withe a total of 6 values and quantities.

I need to some how list every unique value from all 6 fields and total the joint quantity of these values.

I have no idea where to start. I can get the values and their quantities with a simple select * but after that I'm lost.

Thanks for any help even just pointing me in the right direction.

Edited for clarification below.

Table looks like:

```
     ID || value_1 || value_1_qty || value_2 || value_2_qty
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1  ||    562     ||     67        ||     637   ||         12
      2  ||    637     ||     23        ||     768   ||         68
```

Needs results like:

```
      562: 67
      637: 35
      768: 68
```

Comment: You'll get better results from SO if you [edit] your question to include some sample input and a sample result. It's hard to understand what you want from your written question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UNION` to get all the values and quantities into single columns, then you can use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT value, SUM(qty) 
FROM (
    SELECT value_1 AS value, value_1_qty AS qty
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value_2 AS value, value_2_qty AS qty
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value_3 AS value, value_3_qty AS qty
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    ...
) AS x
GROUP BY value
```

It would probably be better to redesign the table so you don't have all these different columns.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to do exactly what I need. Thanks for the help Barmer.